# Failed to create Azure Streaming API settings with error AdvancedHunting-DeviceFileEvents_CustomCollection' is not supported

Tags: security, azure

I want to export Microsoft Defender logs to a SIEM tool.

I have done the following:

- Created a event hub namespace `ns-defender`
- Created a event hub inside the namespace `eh-defender`
- Clicked on Subscriptions -> Production -> Settings: Resource Providers -> microsoft.insights → click Register

Now when I try to go to `security.microsoft.com -> Settings -> Microsoft XDR Defender -> Streaming API -> +Add` then enter the following:

- Name: `sas-defender`
- Foward events to Event Hub
- Event-Hub resource ID: `/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/ns-defender`
- Event-Hub: `eh-defender`

Then I get the following error:

```
Failed to create Streaming API settings

{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Category 'AdvancedHunting-DeviceFileEvents_CustomCollection' is not supported."}
```

What have I done wrong?